# Как строку 256 символов разбить на 8 блоков и поместить в массив uint?

Tags: c#

Имеется строка 256 символов

```
ffeeddccbbaa99887766554433221100f0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff
```

Как ее разбить на 8 блоков и поместить в массив `uint[]`?

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length / 8).Select(n => uint.Parse(s.AsSpan(n * 8, 8), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();`?

Comment: да спасибо. Если вам труда не составит можете объяснить? А то я не все до конца понимаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length / 8)
          .Select(n => uint.Parse(s.AsSpan(n * 8, 8),
                                  NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
          .ToArray();
```

---

Объяснение:

Мы делим строку на блоки по 8 символов, всего таких блоков будет `s.Length / 8`. `Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length / 8)` выдаёт последовательность индексов от 0 do максимального.

Далее, для каждого индекса мы берём нужный блок. Для индекса `n` он начинается с позиции `n * 8`, т. к. длина каждого блока 8 символов, и имеет длину 8, поэтому нужная часть строки задаётся выражением `s.AsSpan(n * 8, 8)`. (Для старых версий C# придётся использовать менее эффективный `Substring`, который аллоцирует новую строку-копию.)

Далее, полученный кусок надо распарсить как 16-ричное число. Для этого берём `uint.Parse` с соответствующими параметрами.

Получившуюся ленивую последовательность материализуем в массив при помощи `.ToArray()`.

Всё!

---

P. S.: В будущих версиях .NET будет добавлен [удобный метод `Chunk`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27449), позволяющий «нарезать» последовательность на куски фиксированного размера, и можно будет написать изящнее:

```
s.Chunk(8)
 .Select(part => uint.Parse(part,
                            NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
 .ToArray();
```

Впрочем, сейчас похожая функциональность есть в пакете [morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) под названием [`Batch`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__2.htm).

P. P. S.: Поскольку новый `System.Range` не реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`, мне прошлось использовать более древний `Enumerable.Range` вместо `(0..s.Length/8).Select...`

Comment: `В будущих версиях .NET` - .NET 6 выйдет в релиз через неделю :) И пишете про `Chunk`, а в коде `Batch`. Логичнее либо блок кода на строчку ниже разместить, либо код изменить на `Chunk`.

Comment: @aepot: Ну вот если в .NET 6 войдёт, тогда отредактирую ответ :) Спасибо, исправил на `Chunk`.